# How to paste from selection buffer in IPython

Tags: ipython

`%paste` seems to paste from the normal `ctrl-c` clipboard. Is there any magic method in `IPython` that supports pasting from selection buffer?

Comment: @WilliamDenman Linux Mint

Comment: You could use `%cpaste`, and then press the middle mouse button. There's nothing exactly equivalent to `%paste` at present.